# How can I get SQL Server Management Studio 2012 to connect to multiple servers automatically on open?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I open SQL Server Management Studio, it only connects to a single Database Server, but I would like it to automatically connect to multiple Database Servers.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking about Management Studio? You could just register the servers that way you don't have to use the connect window again.

Comment: Please explain what you are really trying to achieve. Depending on what's the use case, there might be better solutions like `sqlcmd mode` or `multiserver environment` that satisfy the actual need.

Comment: Judging by your response to @Tara's answer, you do seem to be talking about SSMS, so I've edited mentions of it in to your question.

Answer (score 6):

In Management Studio, go to the View menu and then Registered Servers. Register each of the servers that you want to keep connections for. Then when you open up Management Studio in the future, you just have to go to your register servers and click the ones you need. You can also use the Central Management Servers feature if there are multiple people on your team that would like to share the registered servers. You can group them in various ways, such as by version, by environment, by location, etc.

Comment: Any way to get them to automatically pop up in Object Explorer?

Comment: Drag registered servers on top of object explorer and it will tab then out. Then you have the option to close out object explorer and the next time you open it should show all your registered servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to installing an AddOn to SSMS, try SSMSBoost - it does this and so much more...(http://www.ssmsboost.com/) - I'm not affiliated with SSMSBoost, but I love this tool!

As found at this link

https://serverfault.com/questions/44968/how-can-i-have-sql-server-management-studio-2008-connect-to-my-instances-automat

> If you use the SSMSBoost plugin, then you can set any of your preferred  connections to "Connect object explorer at startup".  This option can be found on the SSMSBoost->Settings->Preferred Connections->List page of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

before to connect with management be sure to register the name of the server on the file host in your machine (current S.O where is your SQL management studio). 
In this way you can connect to the server by your name.

The path on windows to found the file is **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host**   right there are examples of how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free "SSMSConnect" extension for SSMS, which I developed to solve this issue.
https://github.com/ikarasin/SSMSConnect
SSMS versions 18 and 19 are currently supported.